# Selecting multiple ranges from string of ranges

Tags: vba, excel, range, union

I'm trying to select multiple ranges at the same time. Ie. B2:C2, B12:C12, B14:C14.

**Updated code**

```
Sub MarkForDMSLookup()
Dim MarkingString As String
Dim MarkingRange As String

j = 0

For i = 3 To 20 'LastRow()
    If Cells(i, 5) = "Yes" Then
        j = j + 1
        MarkingRange = "B" & i & ":C" & i
        'MsgBox MarkingRange
        If j = 1 Then MarkingString = MarkingRange
        If j > 1 Then MarkingString = MarkingString & ", " & MarkingRange

        If Cells(i, 5) = "No" Then Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End If
Next i

'MsgBox MarkingString

Union(MarkingString).Select
End Sub
```

The `Union`tag gives me a *type mismatch*. Any help to aligning the types would be greatly appreciated.

When limiting the for-loop to go from 2 to 20 i can use the `Range` tag instead of `Union`.

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Change `For i = 3 To LastRow()` to `For i = 3 To LastRow`

Comment: The error come with `Set SelRange = Union(MarkingString)`

I have no error with `LastRow()` but I am going to need this when i expand the code.. :)

Comment: `Set SelRange = range(MarkingString)`

Comment: When doing that, @Jeeped, I get Run-time error '1004' on `Range(MarkingString)`

Comment: The MarkingString comes out like _"B3:C3, B4:C4, B5:C5, ... B85:C85"_

Comment: Just ran this without a problem. `Dim selrng As Range, selstr As String:     selstr = "B3:C3, B4:C4, B5:C5": Set selrng = Range(selstr): selrng.Select`. The problem seems to be in your string construction. Run `Debug.Print MarkingString` just before setting the range object and check the VBE's immediate window.

Comment: First you run the risk of a range address that starts with a comma; second, you need to ensure the range address is under 255 characters or it will fail. I'd use `Union` instead of addresses.

Comment: When I limit the number of rows to look in to only 20 I don't get any errors. with `Union(MarkingString).select` I get _Type mismatch_. Any inputs till how what the mismatch is, @Rory?

Comment: What is the value of LastRow? The idea is that you are limited to a number of non consecutive ranges (I don't have a number to give you), but try to run the same code on a smaller range to see if it works

Comment: @R3uk LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: @StefanMoeberg : I mean the actual value (just a rough estimate is enough) because if it is 1 000 it is not the same as 1 000 000! ;) As your code work in smaller range, let me propose a step by step solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use an autofilter instead of looping:

```
Sub MarkForDMSLookup()
    Dim j As Long
    j = 0

    With Range("E2:E" & LastRow())
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Yes"
        On Error Resume Next
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1, -3).Resize(, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

End Sub
Function LastRow()
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Comment: This is close but not what I need. I need to be able to select the filtered cells, and only the filtered cells.

Comment: Not sure I follow. This does the same as your original code would - i.e. selects only the cells where column E contains "Yes", and hides the others.

Comment: I'm sorry! I made a typo!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MarkForDMSLookup()
Dim MarkingString As String, _
    MarkingRange As String, _
    FirstRun As Boolean, _
    RgMarking As Range, _
    RgTotal As Range, _
    CounT As Long, _
    ToTaL As Long

FirstRun = True
CounT = 0
ToTaL = 0
Set RgTotal = Nothing

For i = 3 To LastRow
    If Cells(i, 5) <> "Yes" Then
        If Cells(i, 5) = "No" Then Cells(i, 5).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        MarkingRange = "B" & i & ":C" & i
        CounT = CounT + 1
        ToTaL = ToTaL + 1
        If FirstRun Then
            MarkingString = MarkingRange
            FirstRun = False
        Else
            MarkingString = MarkingString & ", " & MarkingRange
        End If
        If CounT <> 20 Then

        Else
            On Error GoTo ErrHandler
            Set RgMarking = Range(MarkingString)
            Set RgTotal = Union(RgTotal, RgMarking)
            On Error GoTo 0
            MarkingString = vbNullString
            FirstRun = True
            CounT = 0
        End If
    End If
Next i

Set RgTotal = Union(RgTotal, RgMarking)
RgTotal.Select
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & Err.Number
Resume Next
End Sub
```